# after writing style.scss code and clicking 'watch sass', style.css file is not creating

Tags: css, json, sass

Everything was working perfectly and I changed json file defaults I can't restore it. I am using VS code.

when I click "Watch Sass" in VS Code, only two files are created (style.min.css and style.min.css.map), but I want a third file (style.css) to be created as well.

that's my current json settings:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "liveServer.settings.enableBrowserRefresh": false,
    "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true,
    "liveServer.settings.ChromeDebuggingAttachment": false,
    "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "firefox",
    "[python]": {
        "editor.formatOnType": true
    },
    "liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
        {
            "format": "compressed",
            "extensionName": ".min.css",
            "savePath": "/dist/css"
        }
    ],
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:

[How do I change the settings](https://github.com/glenn2223/vscode-live-sass-compiler/blob/HEAD/docs/faqs.md),

good coding :),

Comment: Please avoid do only-link answers

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).